# Android Studio Open project show "Nothing to show"

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio was working fine last day. But today when i open Android, I can not see my project.
I even tried with

```
file > Open Recent > Project Name
```

but error `cannot load project java.lang.nullpointerexception` appears

I also tried

```
file > Open
```

but file/project explorer shows "nothing to show". Please see screenshot below
[image]

Appreciate if any one can help me selecting my project.

Comment: It shows loading on the top right corner of the prompt window.. wait till it ends and post

Comment: Delete AndroidStudio2.2 folder.  It will work

Comment: Yes but it keeps on loading.. nothing happens

Comment: @RahulGiradkar bro where is that AndroidStudio2.2 folder ??

Comment: Which system your are using Linux or windows

Comment: @Anjum for windows : C:\Users\<YourProfile> and For linux Home/AndroidStudio2.2  it is hidden in linux

Comment: ok, i am doing this and let you know with results.

Comment: @RahulGiradkar - Yes it worked for me. Thank you for your help :-)